# getopt_long acting weirdly

Tags: c++, c, getopt, getopt-long

I'm writing some code for parsing the command line input. The way I use getopt_long is as follows:

```
int c = 0; 
static struct option long_options[] =  
{ 
    {"mode",        1,  NULL,   'm'}, 
    {"help",        0,  NULL,   'h'}, 
    {0,             0,  0,      0} 
}; 
while ((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "mh", long_options, NULL))!=-1) 
{ 
    switch(c) 
    { 
        case 0: 
        { 
            cerr<<"Usage: ./program <-m> <-h>"<<endl; 
            exit(1); 
            break; 
        } 
        case 'm': 
        { 
            if (!strcmp(optarg, "small"))
                mode = 0;
            else if (!strcmp(optarg, "medium"))
                mode = 1;
            else if (!strcmp(optarg, "large"))
                mode = 2;
            else{
                cerr<<"Invalid mode "<<optarg<<endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            break; 
        } 
        case 'h': 
        { 
            cerr<<"See man page for help."<<endl;
            exit(0); 
        } 
        default: 
        { 
            cerr<<"Unrecognized argument!"<<endl; 
            exit(1); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I tested the following:

1)

```
./program
```

The program doesn't enter the while-loop. Variable c is inspected to be -1.

2)

```
./program -h
```

Works well.

3)

```
./program -m small
```

The program exit with Segmentation Fault throwing from strcmp().

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need a colon after options that take an argument, `"m:h"`.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Thanks! Problem 3) is solved, but 1) remains

Comment: If you have no options, getopt won't do anything. What is it you would like to do when no arguments are provided?

Comment: `If there are no more option characters, getopt() returns -1. `
If you want it to enter atleast once, you can change it to a do-while loop..

Comment: My spidey sense tells me you want to require that the "mode" option be set? In that case it's not really an option, it's a required argument and can just be treated normally as part of argv. If you really really want to still make it a non-optional option (hehe), then initialize mode to something else (-1 maybe) and then do a check after the while loop to see if its value has changed.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy That's exactly what I'm trying to do! I will definitely take your advice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to parse options with `getopt_long()` and correctly handle its return values, such as end of options, missing arguments and unknown options:

```
struct Options
{
    std::string username = "guest";

    void parse_command_line(int ac, char** av) try {
        enum {
              HELP
            , USER
        };

        // This array must be in the same order as the enum.
        option const options[] = {
              {"help",            no_argument, nullptr, HELP}
            , {"username",  required_argument, nullptr, USER}
            , {}
        };

        ::opterr = 0;
        for(int c; -1 != (c = getopt_long(ac, av, ":h", options, nullptr));) {
            switch(c) {
            // both short and long option
            case 'h':
            case HELP:
                usage(av, EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;

            // only long option
            case USER:
                username = ::optarg; // 
                break;

            case ':': // missing argument
                throw Exception("--%s: an argument required", options[::optopt].name);

            case '?': // unknown option
                throw Exception("%s: unknown option", av[optind - 1]);
            }
        }

    }
    catch(std::exception& e) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", e.what());
        usage(av, EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
};
```

Note, that it is not necessary to have a corresponding short option for each long option.